# Crystal Reports - No rowset was returned for this table, query or procedure - Crash!

Tags: crystal-reports, crash-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 8.0.1.0 and have an OLEDB connection set as "favourite".
We have several reports being run against a few stored procedures on the database.
Our database is an SQLExpress 2005 named instance.

One of the reports deals with balance, i.e. we have to provide a balance report for a specific company or set of companies.

The customer, however, has specifically asked us to have a separate section to be the last one for a specific economic account typology and in order to do this, we have to separate this one from the others which are instead displayed using two parallel subreports.

Hence our structure should be like follows:

```
                           GENERAL HEADING
                          PATRIMONIAL STATE
                              ...data...
                           ECONOMIC COUNTS
                              ...data...
                         THIRD-PARTY EFFECTS
                              ...data...
```

The first two sections below the general heading are achieved with two parallel subreports, so now we have to display the third section.
Is it clear up to now? Well, as you may well be aware, CR subreports require you to set the database location, regardless if you have set one up already for main report.
The problem, however, is that if I try to set the location pointing to our stored procedure(which returns **ALL** the data for the balance report), the first time it will display the message in subject, and the second time again, but this time it'll also crash.
Our stored procedure has a parameter and both previous subreports(the ones in parallel) are set to the same SP and are working flawlessly.

This crash makes it impossible for me to work on the third section and I'm pretty much at loss as to what would be the best approach to solve the issue at hand.

Any ideas/suggestions?

I would **love** to receive your answers and I hope my problem was clear enough(I'm very willing to further delve into it for clarification if ever needed).

Thank you so much for your time,

Andrea Raimondi

Answer (score 1):

Geez... changing the connection from OLEDB to SQLServer it correctly fetches the rowset and doesn't crash!

I am **speechless**.

Andrew